# Callback function called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am trying to make calendar for my application, when i click on date for first time, callback method is getting called 1 time (as expected), but when i click on date (any date in month) second time then callback is called 2 times(it should be called 1 time) and so on..

When some day in calendar is clicked:

```
onDayClick = function(date, jsEvent, view){
    //alert('Date: ' + date.format() + '\n' + 'Current View: ' + view.name + '\n' + 'Make a form here.');
    //console.log('Called onDayClick ' + global_counter++);
    createForm(function(form){
        console.log('createForm Callback');
        event = {
            start : date                
        }
        onModalRendered(event);
    });
    //$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
}


createForm = function(cb){
    console.log('createForm');
    var form = $('#myModal');
    form.modal('show');
    form.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        cb(form);       
    }); 
    return false;
}
```

Console log output is as follows:

```
Called onDayClick 0 //day clicked in calendar (say, 5 Sep) 
createForm 
createForm Callback
onModalRendered 
Called onDayClick 1 //day clicked in calendar (say, 6 Sep) here callback should be called 1 time
createForm 
createForm Callback 
onModalRendered 
createForm Callback 
onModalRendered
```

I feel i made some mistake in making the callback function. Please, point out my mistake.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: Haven't used jsFiddle. Can give it a try.

Comment: ahhh, i got the culprit, it was `form.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        cb(form);       
    }); ` getting registered multiple time, resulting in multiple invocation of inline function hence, multiple callback functions calling.